# Wordpress hook function

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I'm new to this and need a little help.

here's some sample code i want to change, i want to swap the h3 tags to h5 tags.

Here's the first page

```
<?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_subcategory_title hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', $category );
    ?>

    <h3>
        <?php
            echo $category->name;

            if ( $category->count > 0 )
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', ' <mark class="count">(' . $category->count . ')</mark>', $category );
        ?>
    </h3>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_subcategory_title hook
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', $category );
    ?>
```

I'm trying to replace this part of the code:

```
<h3>
        <?php
            echo $category->name;

            if ( $category->count > 0 )
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', ' <mark class="count">(' . $category->count . ')</mark>', $category );
        ?>
    </h3>
```

with this:

```
<div class="caption-non-move">
      <h5>
        <?php
            echo $category->name;

            if ( $category->count > 0 )
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html');
        ?>
      </h5>
    </div>
```

Here's what i've got so far.

```
<?php
// Add text to content-product-cat to help with styling
add_action('woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'woohook_before_subcategory_title');

function woohook_before_subcategory_title() {
ob_start();

}

add_action('woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'woohook_after_subcategory_title');

function woohook_after_subcategory_title() {
 $subcategory_title = ob_get_clean();
 echo "<div class='caption-non-move'>";
 echo str_replace('h3>', 'h5>', $subcategory_title);
}
?>
```

and here's the second page

```
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>

    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>

</a>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

</li>
```

On the second page i'm trying to replace this part of the code

```
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
```

with

```
<div class="caption"><h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
      <div class="category-main-points"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here's what i have so far for the second page

```
<?php
// Add text to content-product-cat to help with styling
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woohook_before_shop_loop_item_title');

function woohook_before_shop_loop_item_title() {
ob_start();

}

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woohook_after_shop_loop_item_title');

function woohook_after_shop_loop_item_title() {
 $doh_title = ob_get_clean();
 echo "<div class='caption'>";
 echo str_replace('h3>', 'h5>', $doh_title);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the h3 tags are embedded into the template itself (as it seems to be) and you don't want or can't alter the original code. The only way you can do this would be to use php output buffering.

```
<?php
add_action('woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'woohook_before_subcategory_title');

function woohook_before_subcategory_title() {
ob_start();

}

add_action('woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'woohook_after_subcategory_title');

function woohook_after_subcategory_title() {
 $subcategory_title = ob_get_clean();
 echo str_replace('h3>', 'h5>', $subcategory_title);
}
?>
```

Also note that the correct hook for do_action is add_action, not add_filter.

Comment: Thanks, that works a treat, I understand it a little more now, just a follow up, how would i delete or replace this part of the code "<mark class="count">(' . $category->count . ')</mark>', $category )" thanks

Comment: Hi thanks for that but i don't think i understand it any better after trying the next page. I've update the original code to show you what i'm trying to achieve. thanks

Comment: This is where you would use add_filter such as add_filter('woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', 'yourfilterfunct', 10, 2); with 10 being the priority and 2 for the number arguments passed. Then whatever that hook function yourfilterfunct($markstring, $category) returns is the html replacement that will be echoed instead, using either of the two arguments as variables, to make a str_replace() on $markstring or make it your own html string using the $category object.

Comment: Your second action for the second case seems correct except for the naming of the hook function. It needs to be named 'after' like the action itself, not 'before'.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, could you give me an example as I don't understand what you've just put, sorry.

Comment: The correction is: add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woohook_after_shop_loop_item_title');

function woohook_after_shop_loop_item_title() {

Comment: Hi Bry, thanks again, sorry but i understood that part and i've updated the original code to show so it's correct (hopefully), but i forgot there was a bit more code that needed adding, see the second page part that needs replacing and i've now added the code that i want to replace it with. in terms of the not understanding part, it was the first page i.e "This is where you would use add_filter such as add_filter('woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', "

Comment: I unfortunately can't help for every additional request by making the code for you, nor turn this into a discussion board. I gave a concept for replacing templates for when hooks are not available. However if you are gonna replace this with that many custom elements. I would recommend you make it your own custom template instead or edit the files directly. Having so many buffers or hooks for such a small template file, is getting to unnecessary bloat. If the amount of code you have to do becomes so much more complex than the template file itself, hooks are no longer the most viable option.